# Python - Reading a SQL script with multiple queries using 'latin1' encoding | Issue with whitespaces and begins with ascii characters

Tags: python, sql, string

**Overview**
Im currently reading a sql script with multiple queries in python. Once the script is read into python as string type, the code establish connection to the SQL server via sql alchemy. Each query is split by ";" and executed on the SQL server.

**Problem**
The issue is that once the code is read into python, there are spaces between each character. I also noticed that the string start with characters `ÿþ`. How do I remove the spaces without tampering with the actually query and ensure there are no added ascii characters.

NB: For the purpose of this question, I will not be adding the connection to the SQL.

**Step 1**
To replicate the issue, please create the sql script as using code below:

```
--############################################################################################
-- Table 1
--############################################################################################
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[testdb].[TEST]') is not null DROP TABLE [dbo].[testdb].[TEST]  
SELECT TOP (10) * INTO [dbo].[testdb].[TEST] 
FROM [dbo].[testdb].[ACT_SOURCE]
;
--############################################################################################
-- Table 2
--###########################################################################################
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[testdb].[TEST2]') is not null DROP TABLE [dbo].[testdb].[TEST2]  
SELECT TOP (20) * INTO [dbo].[testdb].[TEST2] 
FROM [dbo].[testdb].[ACT_SOURCE]
```

[dbo].[testdb].[ACT_SOURCE] is an existing table. Please keep in the comments as well as the semi-colon. You can save the script as test.sql .

**Step 2**
Read in the sql script

```
import os
str_sql_file= os.path.join(CONFIG.STR_ROOT_FOLDER, 'sql', CONFIG.STR_SQL_FILE_STEP_ONE)

with open(str_sql_file, 'r', encoding='latin1') as file_sql_tmp:
    str_sql = file_sql_tmp.read()
```

**Step 3**
Read each sql query

```
for str_sql_single in str_sql.split(';'):
           print('executing sql: \n {}'.format(str_sql_single))
```

The result looks something like this :

[image: result for sql str in python]

**conda env setup**

```
python 3.11.5
pandas 2.1.4
holidays 0.29
scikit-learn 1.3.0
boto3 1.29.1 
-- if using sqlachemy
sqlachemy 
pyodbc 4.0.39
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source files are encoded as UTF-16, not latin-1.

```
>>> print('a'.encode('utf-16').decode('latin-1'))
ÿþa
```

The extra spaces come from null bytes as UTF-16 uses two bytes to encode characters but as characters in the ASCII range can be encoded with a single byte the other byte is null (`\x00`). The presence of such spaces is usually a strong hint that a UTF-16 source has been incorrectly decoded.

`'ÿþa'` is the result decoding the byte-order mark that UTF-16 inserts at the beginning of encoded text as latin-1.

```
>>> 'a'.encode('utf-16')
b'\xff\xfea\x00'
```